# How to ensure that UNIX sockets are connected to the same address

Tags: unix, ipc

Given file descriptors of two connected AF_UNIX sockets is it possible to ensure that they are indeed connected to the same peer?

A function like [`getpeername`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html) would do but it doesn't seem to support this family.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the definition of [AF_UNIX](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) socket, the socket is the method used by the processes of the local machine.

So, to get the peer(s) of a socket file, you just need to get the list of local processes that have opened the file descriptor.

You can do that using fuser command or lsof. Both unix command will give you the list of processes using the socket, and you may compare the result to status about your question.

Comment: Socket file can be overwritten on disk by a new IPC socket. However, like when you delete a file, for as long as it's open it still exists. lsof will not help me, because there won't be any symbolic name associated with the socket.

Comment: Ok. Let's you are right. 
How do you discover the name of AF_UNIX that there WAS a in a particular directory, and that has been removed before it has been closed because you can see it still open with netstat command ?

Comment: I’m not trying to figure out which process holds it open. I rather have 2 sockets connected to an IPC socket and I want to know if they are connected to the same peer. At this point I may not have symbolic name of the target socket.